# Typescript project compile errors

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am starting with typescript and installed the typing files for node and express,body-parser. When i try to run compile , but on compiling I see the errors that it cannot import express and body parser. But I also installed  the node modules separately for all of them so after tsc compiles the code it would run fine . But the compilation errors are still there.

The Errors

app.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.

app.ts(9,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.

```
 import express = require('express');

let app = express();
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello");
})
// Listen for HTTP traffic
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: @basarat added code snippet and  project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , first mistake with my code i found was that i my app.ts i was not referencing the main.d.ts file. 
`/// <reference path="typings/main.d.ts" />`
then still the errors were coming . 
so installed typings for the following.

```
typings install serve-static --ambient --save
typings install express-serve-static-core --ambient --save
typings install mime --ambient --save
```

and voila, no compile errors

Answer (score 0):

> code it would run fine

TypeScript is like a really powerful linter. It will always try to give you JavaScript even in the presence of type errors. So your code might run fine even with errors.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

> But the compilation errors are still there.

I cannot help you much without you sharing more code / steps you took?

## Samples

This project uses express : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm

Also docs on a quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html